# What does :: mean or do in Puppet?

Tags: puppet

I know Puppet classes tend to be assigned with two colons. But I don't fully understand what the :: does.  When are two colons necessary for defining a class in a Puppet file?

Answer (score 5):

They are used for [namespace seperators](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_namespaces.html#syntax). It is analogous to the /